# Calculation in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql, database

Below is the code I want to apply a logic to subtract a Quantity before update in database ? May i know how to write a logic in code? kindly advise.

Example WMWTContQTy.text value subtract from  DB `[CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[WM_QTY_STATUS]` `CONTAINER_QTY` value before update into DB table

```
protected void WMWT_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            string TransID = WMWTNewID.Text;
            string Date = WMWTDATE.Text;
            string VendorName = WMWTVendorName.Text;
            string Material = WMWTMaterial.Text;
            string NetWeight = WMWTNetWeight.Text;
            string DocNum = WMWTDocNum.Text;
            string Status = WMWTStatus.Text;
            string Locator = WMWTLocator.Text;
            string ContainerQty = WMWTContQty.Text;
            string ContainerType = WMWTContType.Text;
            string ContainerSource = WMWTContSource.Text;
            string Remark = WMWTRemark.Text;
            string CreateDate = WMWTCDATE.Text;
            string CreateUser = WMWTCUSER.Text;

            string UpdateWMMRSQL = "UPDATE [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[WM_QTY_STATUS] SET 
            STATUS = '" + Status + "',CONTAINER_QTY ='" + ContainerQty + "'";

            string InsertWMMRSSQL = 
            "INSERT INTO [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[WM_TRANS_HISTORY] 
            (TRANSID,DATE,VENDOR_NAME,MATERIAL,NET_WEIGHT,DOC_NUM,STATUS,CONTAINER_QTY,
            CONTAINER_TYPE,CONTAINER_SOURCE,LOCATOR,REMARK,CREATEDATE,CREATEUSER)   
            VALUES ('" + TransID + "','" + Date + "','" + VendorName + "','" + Material 
            + "','" + NetWeight + "','" + DocNum + "','" + Status + "','" + 
            ContainerQty + "','" + ContainerType + "','" + ContainerSource + "','" + 
            Locator + "','" + Remark + "','" + CreateDate + "','" + CreateUser + "')";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            SqlCommand Insertcmd = new SqlCommand(InsertWMMRSSQL, con);
            SqlCommand InsertHisscmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateWMMRSQL, con);

            con.Open();

            Insertcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            InsertHisscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            con.Close();

            Response.Redirect("WM_WT.aspx?stat=insert");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first. As per your current design you can achieve the same as follows:

```
string UpdateWMMRSQL = "UPDATE [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[WM_QTY_STATUS] 
SET STATUS = '" + Status + "',CONTAINER_QTY = CONTAINER_QTY - '" + ContainerQty + "'";
```

But this is a very bad design and would lead you some other problems like `SQL Injection`. So better use parametrized query to avoid this as explained in th post of @nunespascal.

Comment: Thank u for reply, but how i apply it in parameter ? can you show an example ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in the update statement itself

```
UPDATE [CIMProRPT01].[dbo].[WM_QTY_STATUS]
SET 
STATUS = '@Status',
CONTAINER_QTY = CONTAINER_QTY - '@Change'
```

Use parametrized queries so that you are safe from SQL injection

```
using(SqlCommand UpdateHisscmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateWMMRSQL, con))
{
  UpdateHisscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);
  UpdateHisscmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", WMWTContQTy.text);
  UpdateHisscmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: HI, i had try add in SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CIMProRPT01ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                SqlCommand Insertcmd = new SqlCommand(InsertWMMRSSQL, con);
                SqlCommand InsertHisscmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateWMMRSQL, con);
               
                UpdateWMMRSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", Status);
                UpdateWMMRSQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Change", WMWTContQty.Text);

                con.Open();
but it had an error. kindly advise.

Comment: I renamed your update command variable so that it wasn't called Insert... If you take only part of the code, you will have check the variable names you are using. In the code you show, ` UpdateWMMRSQL` is not defined, and hence the error.